# Can a complex arrangement of diodes do computation?

Tags: graphs, theory

If I have a bunch of diodes arranged in some complex, directed graph, can I get it to do computation?

I mean will it add voltages and, for example, as I insert voltage sources in-between the diodes?  Can I implement a J/K flip-flop?

Thanks.

Comment: If you can implement an "AND" gate and a "NOT" gate then you can compute anything really

Comment: (Given (resistors and non-*controlled*) voltage/power sources, you still need some characteristic curve with a significant section of negative slope.) There is [Electrical Engineering@SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @nirshahar:  I don't believe that will give you the capacity to do iteration or implemenet a stack.

Comment: What model of computation are you working with? "Computqtion" can mean a lot of things, for example - one common model when dealing with circuits is [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_circuit)

Comment: @nirshahar:  That's a cool example.  The model of computation is a simple Turing machine.